# Type mismatch found: scala function => Unit required: java.util.Consumer

Tags: java, scala

I'm getting the following error in Scala 2.11:

```
Error:(54, 85) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.pig.data.Tuple => Unit
 required: java.util.function.Consumer[_ >: org.apache.pig.data.Tuple]
    pigTest.getAlias("productData").forEachRemaining((x: org.apache.pig.data.Tuple) => print(x))
```

I'm confused because my function **is** a consumer so I don't know why it's being rejected or how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Scala 2.11 doesn't have good interoperability with Java 8 functions. The Pig code I'm calling is Java code that expects a Java consumer, so per [this post](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/2014/10/12/calling-java-8-functions-from-scala) I have to wrap the scala function.

Resulting code:

```
pigTest.getAlias("productData").forEachRemaining(toJavaConsumer((x: org.apache.pig.data.Tuple) => print(x)))
```

where:

```
  def toJavaConsumer[T](consumer: (T) => Unit): Consumer[T] ={
    new Consumer[T] {
      override def accept(t: T): Unit = {
        consumer(t)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's no benefit from `: ClassTag` in your answer, only drawbacks (e.g. it disallows using it for `A => Unit` where `A` is a type parameter of a class or a method).

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about that! I ran into issues before with a generic method without ClassTag so I just included it but I didn't know if it would be useful or not.